# Inserting Timestamp in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp

I want to add the current data and time in a specific column with any edit in whole sheet. I tried to write a script and got a little bit success but could not get desired result.

When I run the below script then it insert the time stamp in the very next column but I want to insert the timestamp in a specific column e.g in Column D.

Secondly it only works when I change values in a cell, but I want to add time stamp also when I change even color of a cell too.

```
function onEdit() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet

    var r = s.getActiveCell();

    if( r.getColumn() ) { //checks the column

      var nextCell = r.offset (0,1) ;

     // if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?

        nextCell.setValue(new Date() );
    }
  }
}
```

Kindly help me to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to insert the timestamp in a specific column e.g in Column D:

```
function onEdit() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet

    var r = s.getActiveCell();

    if( r.getColumn() ) { //checks the column

      var nextCell = s.getRange('D' + r.getRow()); // change D to any column needed

      // if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?

      nextCell.setValue(new Date() );
    }
  } 
}
```

Notes:

- > > **`onEdit(e)`** runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.
- tests show `onEdit` runs when cells borders are changed
- `onEdit` does NOT run when color is changed, font is changed.

Comment: Kindly inform me which method needs to use for color change or even any type of change?

Thanks

Comment: There's currently no method that supports color change or even any type of change. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/